# Importing CSV files always fail

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

My problem is failing to import any csv file from my laptop
I always get errors ( 2068, 1083,or 3948 )
I have tried Changing in my.ini text file ,but editing is prevented
I wrote this code

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

I get this result

```
'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\'
```

so transferred csv files to this pass -- another failure also
My codes are:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/covid_death.CSV'
INTO TABLE death
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TERMINATED BY'\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

these lines applied for workbench and command lines too(MySQL 8.0)
*When I use "Import Data Wizard" loads error in integer or Truncated values error"

Comment: Why are you using a Unix style path on Windows? The first query gave you the correct format to use.

Comment: If you're getting truncated values, it would be helpful if you showed us some sample data And the table definition. (We're not psychic.)

Comment: When you do get error messages, please include the WHOLE error message, not just the error code. And be certain to include the exact code you actually ran along with each error message.

Comment: LOAD DATA **LOCAL** needs `@@local_infile` to be enabled on both server and client side, and it is applied for remote files uploading primarily. Remove `LOCAL` keyword, and use **complete** filepath which includes the drive letter.